# Comibine conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a better way to write this?

```
if a == 'new' || a == 'create'
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Instead of checking `a` twice, I thought I could combine the first line with one `a`. I'm looking at something like:

```
if a == ['new' || 'create']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is :

```
if %w(new create).include? a
  #code here
else
  #code
end
```

Comment: this solution creates an extra object in memory. whereas the code in the original question does not. I personally do not see anything wrong with the original code.

Comment: @akonsu Nothing is *wrong* with it, they were asking for an alternative.

Comment: @akonsu its not all about performance. @victor you can make it even terser `%w(new create).include? a`

Comment: @AJcodez you make it sound as if the original code is more difficult to maintain. I think it is clearer to understand that the idiom with the array.

Comment: @akonsu to each his/her own for sure. I use `include?` in my ruby code cause its easier on my eyes, and extends well to 3 or 4 options. doesnt matter much either way

Comment: @AJcodez yes, you are right I modified my code with your `%w(new create).include? a`. that's good. I liked that.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to do the test several ways, but doing it on a single line isn't necessarily the best idea. One of the clearest ways to write it in Ruby is to use a `case` statement:

```
case a
when 'new', 'create'
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

The advantage to doing this is you can easily add additional tests by appending them to the `when` list.

You could get down and dirty with a regex:

```
%w[foo renew new created create].each do |w|
  puts w[/^(?:new|create)$/]
end
```

Which would generate output like:

```
# >> 
# >> 
# >> new
# >> 
# >> create
```

`# >>` is the output marking a new line when using Sublime Text. This means only `new` and `create` matched.

I don't especially recommend that unless you understand regular expressions, but it can be an extremely fast way to check against a huge number of options.

Comment: I don't think your second part is helpful. With just the case statement part, your answer will look much better.

Comment: The second part is extremely helpful when checking against a long list of possible values. The regex engine is much faster than iterating over an array, or using `include`.

Comment: @theTinMan out of curiosity would you use a set or a regexp for say 100+ options?

Comment: I've used a regex for well over 100 options. A set can be much faster than an array when searching, because it doesn't take a linear search to find something, since `Set` is basically a hash key -- it might be faster to generate a hash actually. If the target words are static, it's possible to generate a highly optimized regex that I suspect would be highly efficient, so much so I'd have to do a benchmark to see if set was worth using for the same sort of test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002494/whats-the-best-way-to-apply-many-perl-regular-expression-tests/4002558#4002558